# I'm trying to push an item to Note object but got an error,'Uncaught TypeError: noteObj.push is not a function'

Tags: javascript, json, function, object, push

```
let addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');
let addTxt = document.getElementById('addTxt');


addBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {

    let addTxtVal = addTxt.value || '';
    let notes = localStorage.getItem('notes');
    if (notes == null) {
        noteObj = [];
    }
    else {
        noteObj = JSON.parse(notes);
    }
    noteObj.push(addTxtVal);
    localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(noteObj));

})
```

Comment: try `console.log(notes)` inside the `else`. It appears that it isn't an array as you expect.

Comment: it looks like noteObj is not initialized correctly try to move it outside the if statement